# Library for .NET that returns SPARQL results in some structured List instead of standard XML format?

Tags: .net, xml, collections, sparql

Is there any Library for .NET that returns SPARQL results in some structured List instead of standard XML format? I am using SemWeb. I could not find any such method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SemWeb does appear to provide the building blocks for what you want. Looking at [the documentation](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/semweb-current/doc/query.html) it seems [`QueryResultSink`](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/semweb-current/apidocs/SemWeb.Query/QueryResultSink.html) is what you want. You could build a list of results using that, or work directly with the results as they arrive.

Alternatively try [dotnetrdf](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/). [This introduction](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=Querying%20with%20SPARQL) shows that queries result in a [SparqlResultSet](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/index.asp?Topic=VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlResultSet) that you can iterate through.

From the examples:

```
TripleStore store = new TripleStore();
// ...data...
Object results = store.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}");
if (results is SparqlResultSet) {
    SparqlResultSet rset = (SparqlResultSet)results; 
    foreach (SparqlResult result in rset) { 
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes with SemWeb you can write your own QueryResultSink implementation to get the results back in some other form if you want a list of results.  If you use my dotNetRDF library as comment_bot suggests you get a SparqlResultSet which you can iterate through and you can index into each SparqlResult object using variable names or integer index

Comment: @RobV is there a way to remove language tags like @en and type tags like ^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int. from results?
Offcource I can manipulate strings but is there any way availabel in library?

Comment: If you know that a value for one variable is a LiteralNode (try using the `NodeType` property or doing `x is LiteralNode`) you can cast it to a LiteralNode and then use the `Value` property to just get the string value excluding the datatype/language tag